# Accessibility Issue for Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a module in `/models/pet_data.rb` that looks like this:

```
module PetData
  def self.table_name_prefix
    ""
  end
end
```

I then have a class in `/models/pet_data/pet.rb` that looks like this:

class PetData::Pet < ApplicationRecord
end

Finally, there is a controller in `/controllers/api/v1/pet_data/pets_controller.rb` with a create method, like this:

```
def create
    # Make pet 
    @pet = PetData::Pet.new(permitted_attributes(PetData::Pet))

    # Authorize and scope
    authorize @pet
    skip_policy_scope

    # Create
    @pet.save!

    # Return
    @pet
  end
```

Now, that throws the error `*** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant Api::V1::PetData::PetsController::PetData` However, if I put `::PetData` in the first line of that create method, no error.

Is rails autoload not loading my modules here or something? How do I get it to recognize PetData::Pet as a proper thing?

Comment: What's this accomplishing? Are you trying to put all your models into a module?

Comment: @Schwern I'm namespacing by nesting things in modules for organization reasons, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force Rails' autoload to resolve `PetData::Pet` in development as a top level constant by qualifying it, eg:

```
# Api::V1::PetData::PetsController
def create
  ::PetData::Pet
end
```

You might need to restart your dev server / console if you have Bootsnap enabled and this is the first file you're adding in `/models/pet_data`.

Non-comprehensive explanation on how Rails' autoloading works:

1. When you call `A::B`, Rails will resolve `A` first.
2. If `A` is already loaded, Rails will use the directory nesting for the resolved constant instead of re-resolving it. Looking up the directory nesting for a constant is a slow process as it needs to go through the file system.
3. If constant `A` is not loaded, Rails will search `autoload_paths` for a file
   named `a.rb`, which should define a class or module named `A`.
4. If there's no file named `a.rb`, Rails will look for a directory named `a` in `autoload_paths`. If one is found, Rails will create a module named `A` and continue to autoload `B` within directory `a`
5. If Rails is not able to autoload `B` within directory `a`, an error will be raised.

---

So why does this work flawlessly everywhere except in this particular `PetData::PetsController` controller?

**The PetData constant has already been loaded**. Hence, Rails assumes that any constant nested after `PetData` will be stored under `/app/controllers/api/v1/pet_data`

You need Rails to load the correct file. This can be done by:

1. Indicating to Rails that the `PetData` constant that you're referring to is `::PetData` instead of `Api::V1::PetData`. This will trigger autoload.
2. Adding `require_dependency <path to pet_data/pet.rb>` to the top of
   your controller. Rails will then load the file directly before evaluating the rest of your controller code.

Comment: Well, yes, but this shouldn't be necessary. I'd like to determine how to solve this so that it works properly by loading the models as it should.

Comment: I've restarted the server multiple times. Also restarted Spring. Not using bootsnap. It finds every other namespaced/nested model fine so far, but PetData namespace seems to not be autoloading. I'd like to avoiding having to explicitly call this one model, as it seems to be a bandaid on an actual issue.

Comment: @steventnorris Explained in detail why it happens for this one model.

Comment: This is confusing to me since the Identity module doesn't have this problem. api/v1/identity/users_controller.rb uses `Identity::User` fine without running into this issue. Is there a reason why that one wouldn't be failing but PetData::Pet inside of the pets_controller.rb is? Seems like that would cause the same flaw.

Comment: If `Identity::User` is autoloaded first, you won't have any problems. That would most likely have happened during initialization (eg. by Devise). You should be able to achieve the same effect by referencing `PetData::Pet` in an initializer (database connection sequence issues may apply :P)

Comment: That makes sense. I'm using Devise so it likely is an initializer then. I haven't looked into any sort of custom initializer for Rails, but it seems to make sense that if I have a custom initializer that just includes all the models. It feels... uncomfortable, but could work.

Comment: I go into high alert for constant lookup issues the moment I see two constants which a) have the same name b) are not fully qualified. Fully qualifying both of them  feels like a very natural solution to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Resolving constants is complicated](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html). Autoloading makes it more complicated. The particular case you cite is [very complicated](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-algorithms-qualified-references). Getting your models to work inside modules makes it even more complicated.

You could mess around with `config.autoload_paths`, however...

> But using `autoload_paths` on its own in the past (pre-rails 5) developers might configure `autoload_paths` to add in extra locations (e.g. lib which used to be an autoload path list years ago, but no longer is). However this is now discouraged for most purposes, as it is likely to lead to production-only errors. It is possible to add new locations to both `config.eager_load_paths` and `config.autoload_paths` but use at your own risk.

---

What I recommend is turning autoload off entirely and use eager loading in all environments. This avoids much of the complexity of autoloading (eager loading will sometimes autoload), and it brings your dev and test environments closer to production avoiding certain types of release bugs.

Turn on eager loading in `config/application.rb` and remove autoloading from your environment configs.

```
config.eager_load = true
```

Rails 5 will load everything in `app/` or `app/*/concerns/`, it does not look deeper. See `bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'`. You *might* have to tell it to look for your nested models (I'm writing this answer from memory).

```
config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/pet_data)
```

If eager loading in development is slow, use a gem such as [bootsnap](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap) to make loading the application faster. If that's not fast enough, try [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) as well, but note it has some caveats.

Comment: I feel like this may solve my problem. It certainly smells like an autoload issue. My only problem is this initiative is a code migration, and I was fully taking advantage of the non-eager loading and testing things one controller at a time With eager load on, I need to go sure up some code I wasn't using so it'll all load at boot. Will report back. Thanks for the detailed breakdown. Autoload is a small bit of a blackbox to me still.

Comment: This was absolutely the issue. Since the PetData module had not been autoloaded yet, but was being called as PetData::Pet, the autoload lookup was assuming a relative pathing. This is because of the nested folder PetData/Pet inside models, which you have to have due to Rails' need to have the folders match the namespaces, but it does mess up autoload. Eager loading corrected that. I could likely have added some sort of * based path to eager_load_paths as well, but that gets less reliable. May stick with just full eager_load for now.

Comment: Autoloading in `/models` and `/controllers` is pretty much an established standard. Don't think turning off auto loading is warranted if this is the only issue on the table.

Comment: I spoke too soon. This worked, for a bit, then it didn't. And now it seems to be intermittently a problem. Like the third or fourth time, it fails with the same error.

Comment: I have added more detail from testing if either you or @fylooi are able to give any more insight. This one is driving me up a wall.

Comment: @steventnorris Hmm. Does it happen without Spring?

Comment: It does. I tried restart Spring, then just removed it entirely and get the same problem.